# stopping a query while in execution

Tags: database

This question i'm asking because i don't know about this.
Is it possible to stop a query while it is executing and get the results that it produced in up-to now execution,without fully executing the query? 
what i mean is we get the partially executed query results by stopping the query while it is executing, is it possible?
using some kind of trigger or something to stop the query?

Comment: This may depend on the version of database server you are using.  It would be useful to list that information in your question.

Comment: i'm using Microsoft SQL server 2008

Answer (score 0):

it is possible by using cursors in t-sql, mssqlserver.

Comment: any suggestions how i can do that??

Comment: yes, you can follow these steps basically; 1- create a stored procedure, 2- create a cursor by using DECLARE cursor_name FOR [SELECT  Statement], 3- open cursor by using OPEN cursor_name 4-declare some variables which stores values in the database row by row, 4- FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_name INTO (Variables) this code reads the first row of the result returning from query, 5- youı can control data, when you close the cursor. your query is stopped.